# How to assign textbox value to another class in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to assign `textbox` value to another class, but I do only this in main class :

```
public string TextBox1Text
{   
    get { return textBox1.Text; } 
    set { textBox1.Text = value; } 
}
```

How can I assign this value in second class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create the same property in the second class and pass it over in the main class:

```
public class SecondClass
{
    public string TextBox1Text {  get; set; }
}

public class MainClass
{
    SecondClass sc = new SecondClass();


    public string TextBox1Text
    {   
        get { return textBox1.Text; } 
        set { textBox1.Text = value; } 
    }


    public MainClass
    {   
        sc.TextBox1Text = this.TextBox1Text;
    }
}
```